# Use of "werden sein"

Tags: verb

If we are to translate "I will be in Berlin 3 days later" to German, which is correct?

1. Ich werde 3 Tage später in Berlin sein.
2. Ich werde 3 Tage später in Berlin.

Is only 1 correct? Werden dosn't have a meaning of "will be"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ich werde 3 Tage später in Berlin sein.
>
> <s>Ich werde 3 Tage später in Berlin.</s>
>
> Ich werde 3 Tage später in Berlin ankommen.
>
> Ich werde 3 Tage später in Berlin übernachten.

*Werden* is the *Futur I* auxiliary in these sentences. Auxiliaries cannot stand alone, they need another verb which tense/voice/mood they modify.

---

*Sein* itself is an auxiliary often enough, but not in your original sentence.

> Ich bin Vater geworden.

Here, *sein (1. Person: bin)* is an auxiliary, while *werden (Partizip II: geworden)* is used as a full verb. This construction is the *Perfekt* tense of *werden*.

Comment: wow, that's now clear to me. danke!

Comment: it's interesting werden can be a general verbe meaning "become" not like "will" in English(pure auxiliary verb). maybe that's what confused me earlier.